# Geometrically irreducible singular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445140/intersection-of-a-hyperplane-and-a-curve). Let $C$ be a projective curve (possibly singular) over a field k, and say that it is integral and assume that it contians a smooth point $p$, rational over k. Let us also assume that the genus is 1. I want to show that this curve is goemetrically integral - but I am not at all sure of how this should be done. Is this true? My main goal is to show that it is a cubic, but first I'd like to show the geometrically integral part.